# ATMEGA8A + SPI memory strange behavior

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, atmel, eeprom

I've bought SPI memory [MX25L8006EPI](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MX25L8006EPI-12G-MX25L8006EPI-IC-DIP-8-MX-BIOS-Serial-Flash-Memory-NEW-/291877678999) and now I try to connect it to ATMEGA8A to test it. The schematic is very simple and doesn't change from others over the internet:

[image]

ATMEGA8A works at 8Mz internal oscillator, 3.3V. The fuses are HIGH: 0xD1, LOW: 0xE4.

I use Atmel Studio 7 for coding and AVRISP mkII to programming the uC.
Since EEPROM needs 3.3V I've connected 5V 700mA power supply module using LM317 as you can see on the scheme. I don't think it matters but anyway ...

The code is also very simple, I've partly copied that from some page in the Internet:

```c
#define SLAVESELECT (PORTB &= ~(1<<PORTB2))
#define SLAVEDESELECT (PORTB |= (1<<PORTB2))

#define WREN  6
#define WRDI  4
#define RDSR  5
#define WRSR  1
#define READ  3
#define WRITE 2
#define RDID 0x9F

#define byte unsigned char

void SPI_Init()
{
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB2)|(1<<PORTB3)|(1<<PORTB5);
    SLAVEDESELECT;
    //SPSR |= (1<<SPI2X);
    SPCR |= (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1 << SPR1);
    _delay_ms(10);
}

byte SPI_Transfer(volatile byte data)
{
    SPDR = data;
    while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
    return SPDR;
}

void Get_Identification(byte data[3])
{
    SLAVESELECT;
    SPI_Transfer(RDID);
    data[0] = SPI_Transfer(0xFF);
    data[1] = SPI_Transfer(0xFF);
    data[2] = SPI_Transfer(0xFF);
    SLAVEDESELECT;
}

byte GetStatus()
{
    byte status;
    SLAVESELECT;
    SPI_Transfer(RDSR);
    status = SPI_Transfer(0xFF);
    SLAVEDESELECT;
    return status;
}

void SetWriteEnable(short ebable)
{
    SLAVESELECT;
    SPI_Transfer((ebable != 0) ? WREN : WRDI);
    SLAVEDESELECT;
}

void SetStatus(byte status)
{
    SetWriteEnable(1);
    SLAVESELECT;
    SPI_Transfer(WRSR);
    SPI_Transfer(status);
    SLAVEDESELECT;
    _delay_ms(100);
}

int main(void)
{
    SPI_Init();
    byte status = 0x1C;
    DEBUG_PRINT("\r\nSet status:%d\r\n",status);
    SetStatus(status);
    status = GetStatus();
    DEBUG_PRINT("\r\nGet status:%d\r\n",status);
    byte buffer[3];
    Get_Identification(buffer);
    DEBUG_PRINT("Byte0:%x\r\n", buffer[0]);
    DEBUG_PRINT("Byte1:%x\r\n", buffer[1]);
    DEBUG_PRINT("Byte2:%x\r\n", buffer[2]);

    while (1) 
    {       
    }
}
```

`DEBUG_PRINT` is my function to send formatted string throught USART. I use it to print out debug info.

Everything looks fine but when I run that I get some strange behavior. The output is:

```
Set status:28
Get status:24
Byte0:80
Byte1:0
Byte2:10
```

Firstly I set status register using `WRSR` opcode. it should set it to 00011100 but when I read the status using `RDSR` opcode I get 00011000.

Ok, maybe there is some trouble with status register. Then I try to read ID register using `RDID` opcode. It should return 3 bytes - 0xC2 0x20 0x14. But insted I get 0x80 0x0 0x10.

It would be understandable if I get no answer or all 0x00 or 0xFF. But here I read some answer, the problem that the response is totally wrong. Even more interesting is that if I connect the EEPROM to Arduino using at least the same code it works without problem.

I feel that the problem is quite small. It looks that maybe some data order wrong or transfer speed or something like that but I can't get it work.

Comment: SPI clock phase and polarity settings are match the EEPROM's requirements?

Comment: Yes, the chip works in SPI modes 0 and 3. Currently CPOL=0, CPHA=0 so it in mode 0 but I've also tried mode 3 - the same result.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [datasheet](http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/7729793115580672852), all the blocks are protected when BP2:0 is set to 5, 6, or 7. Perhaps when you set it to 7, the memory only sets it to 6, since it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @UncleO! Yes, you're right. The memory could be protected by setting BP to 5, 6, or 7.  But` BP2` is writable and should be set. Also, if I send `11111111` and then read the status it returns the same wrong result(`00011000`). At least `SRWD` should be set. And if I connect the chip to `Arduino` all the bits of status register are set without problem